# Можно ли так изменить предложение, чтобы не обособлять оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, определения

Из современной художественной литературы:

***Воодушевленная**, я взяла с кафедры газеты, стараясь не испортить манжеты своей кремовой блузки черной типографской краской.*

Как **перестроить** предложение, чтоб **не обособлять** определение.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Тема:** Определение всегда обособляется, если относится к личному **местоимению**. Но оно не обособляется, если связано **по смыслу** не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, в состав которого входит. **[Розенталь, пункт 2 (3)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)**

*Это первый день работы Анимант в большой университетской библиотеке (Лондон, 1890 год). Обязанностей так много, неужели она не справится! Старший библиотекарь встретил неприветливо (что она умеет, чай приносить?), да еще мальчишка-разносчик нагрубил (шикарная крошка!) . Ну уж его-то она сумела поставить на место, этим и **воодушевлена.***

Comment: Воодушевленно я взяла газеты... Я воодушевилась и взяла газеты...

Comment: А определение где? Это тема обособления определений.

Comment: А это определение? Я что-то не уверен, больше похоже на полупредикативный оборот. Воодушевленная девочка взяла... - тут определение, а Воодушевленная, я взяла ... - полупредикатив.

Comment: По Розенталю  не обособляются определения 3) связанные по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, в состав которого они входят. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109  По грамматике это дуплексивы с двойной связью (с подлежащим и сказуемым). Обычно такие конструкции образуются с глаголами движения или состояния, выступающими в роли знаменательной связки. А с глаголом «взяла»  возможна такая связь?